# Turtlebot doesn't stop after killing the command velocity

Tags: turtlebot, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everyone,
I am running two turtlebots  (kobuki) with gazebo1.9 and I provided command velocities to each turtlebot using “rostopic pub” command. I noticed that turtlebot keep moving after I killed the command velocity using “Control tab  +c”.
I am wondering if this anomaly is due to the inertia values for my wheels or something else
Thanks for any help with this issue

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/159926/turtlebot-doesn%27t-stop-after-killing-the-command-velocity/) by [Robert1](https://answers.ros.org/users/12391/robert1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2014-05-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2014-05-04**:
Have faced similar problems with Roomba

**Comment by [Robert1](https://answers.ros.org/users/12391/robert1/) on 2014-05-05**:
Somebody gave a tip to sent 0 command velocity.
rostopic pub /cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist '[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]' '[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]'

That command stopped the turtlebot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe that unless a value of zero gets published, then the last value is what is used by the bot.  Killing the publication command doesn't force a value of zero to be published, so the bot continues with the last speed it received.

---

Originally posted by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) with karma: 486 on 2014-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robert1](https://answers.ros.org/users/12391/robert1/) on 2014-05-05**:
I agree with you. I will take this for final answer

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The gazebo plugin might not have a timeout on incoming commands when they stop being published it may continue to execute the last received command.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-05-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robert1](https://answers.ros.org/users/12391/robert1/) on 2014-05-05**:
Hi Tfoote,
In order to add a timeout on the incoming commands, Do i need to change the source code of the pluging? or is there another way to add a timeout? I installed Gazebo$gazebo-ros-pack from binaries and the turtlebot from source. For now, I send a 0 command velocity to stop the turtlebot. Thanks a lot for your help

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-05-05**:
You could look for a parameter that might enable this. If there isn't I'm sure a patch is appreciated.